# is it possible to retrieve some block transactions using bitcoin-core?

Tags: transactions, block

I'm trying to fetch specific block transactions, is it possible to do so using bitcoin-core?

for example block number: `517716` can I get hex transactions or even just the txid's of that block?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you saying you want to retrieve all the transactions that were mined in a specific block?  In what format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use the `getblockhash` and `getblock` commands. You would do:

```
getblockhash 517716
```

and this will return you the block hash for block 517716. Then you can do

```
getblock <hash> 2
```

where `<hash>` is the hash from `getblockhash`. This will give you the full block details with the full details of all of the transactions in the block. If you just want txids, change the `2` to a `1`.

---

Note that this only works if you are not in pruned mode. If you are pruning, there is no guarantee that you still have the block.